# LOAD DATA en Mysql no reconoce el último valor

Tags: mysql, importación

Estoy intentando cargar estos datos guardados en un `.txt` usando MySQL.

Los datos están separados por una tabulación, una vez llegado al final realizo el siguiente registro en una nueva línea, tal como se muestra a continuación:

```
1   449765.5880 4467863.9590    630.0001
2   449761.3831 4467866.6643    630.0001
3   449757.1781 4467869.3696    630.0001
```

Para ello creo la siguiente tabla usando el siguiente código:

```
create table PuntosMetro( 
FID int auto_increment, 
id_opera INT Not null, 
Costo_1 double  Not null, 
Costo_2 double  Not Null, 
articulo double  Not Null, 
constraint pk_fid_puntom primary key (FID) );
```

Para cargar los datos uso la siguiente función LOAD DATA INFILE de la siguiente forma:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server
5.7\\Uploads\\datos.txt' INTO TABLE PuntosMetro  FIELDS TERMINATED BY  '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (id_opera ,Costo_1 ,Costo_2 ,articulo);
```

Lo cual me devuelve el siguiente error:

> ```
> Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'articulo' at row 1
> ```

No se a que se debe este error, porque el último dato está bien definido y separado igual que los demás por una tabulación. ¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Revisa la longitud del campo en la tabla y en el archivo, el tamaño del campo en la tabla debe ser al menos igual a longitud del dato en el archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Su problema debe estar relacionado con el carácter usado para la terminación de líneas. En su plataforma, Windows, intente usar `\r\n`, `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`. En mi caso, por ser plataforma Unix, uso `\n`, `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`.

Fichero o Archivo (TSV): `'/path/to/file/datos.txt'`

```bash
1   449765.5880 4467863.9590    630.0001
2   449761.3831 4467866.6643    630.0001
3   449757.1781 4467869.3696    630.0001
```

Línea de comando MySQL:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PuntosMetro`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PuntosMetro` (
    ->   `FID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `id_opera` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `Costo_1` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    ->   `Costo_2` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    ->   `articulo` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    ->   CONSTRAINT `pk_fid_puntom` PRIMARY KEY (`FID`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/datos.txt'
    -> INTO TABLE `PuntosMetro`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    -> (`id_opera` , `Costo_1`, `Costo_2`, `articulo`);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'articulo' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE `PuntosMetro`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/datos.txt'
    -> INTO TABLE `PuntosMetro`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> (`id_opera` , `Costo_1`, `Costo_2`, `articulo`);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `FID`,
    ->   `id_opera`,
    ->   `Costo_1`,
    ->   `Costo_2`,
    ->   `articulo`
    -> FROM
    ->   `PuntosMetro`;
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
| FID | id_opera | Costo_1     | Costo_2      | articulo |
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
|   1 |        1 |  449765.588 |  4467863.959 | 630.0001 |
|   2 |        2 | 449761.3831 | 4467866.6643 | 630.0001 |
|   3 |        3 | 449757.1781 | 4467869.3696 | 630.0001 |
+-----+----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funcionó, tan sencillo como esto, y lo intenté de mil maneras